# ERROR: While executing gem ... (NameError) uninitialized constant Gem::RDoc

Tags: rubygems

When trying to uninstall a gem (`gem uinstall <gem-name>`), I see:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::RDoc
```

How do I successfully uninstall a gem?

Answer (score 17):

Based on info in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2483), I did:

```
gem install rdoc
```

After that, the error no longer appeared.

Comment: I needed to install `gem install rdoc --no-document` because of [undefined method `reset' for RDoc::TopLevel:Class when installing a new Ruby gem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38988161/387194) this happen when installing inside Docker.

Comment: The funny thing about this is to uninstall a gem I need to install another gem first... uhmmm

Comment: It's actually insane that to uninstall something you need to install something, but it works

Comment: not working....

Comment: @jcubic I am getting error `uninitialized constant Gem::RDoc` even when using `gem install rdoc --no-document`   (under cygwin)

Comment: removing ~/.gemrc (where I used to put `gemhome: /usr/share/rubygems`) and keeping working with `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin` in .bashrc did the trick.

Comment: @user1767316 I have no idea. Please ask a separate question.